# What does the character set [^] mean in regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Source:[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)

Explaining how a dot character (.) should be used, the documentation says:

> So to match a pattern across multiple lines, the character set [^] can be used (if you don't mean an old version of IE, of course), it will match any character including newlines.

Regarding the ^ character, it says:

> Matches beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately after a line break character.

Obviously ^ is used to mark which character begins a line, not to represent any kind of character. So the question is: how could [^] match any character including newlines?

Comment: `[]` is used to denote a match for anything matching a token in the brackets. If the first character is `^`, i.e. `[^]` it means anything **not** matching tokens in the brackets. So if there are no tokens, it matches everything (literally, there is nothing that doesn't match).

Comment: Because you miss the [] which makes the difference.  [abc] means match character a or b or c, while [] means match null.  Now [^abc] matching any character NOT a, b or c, while [^] means match NOT null, means anything.  This is my own way to remember it but indeed it's just the DEFINITION of what [^] is: `matches any character, including newline`

Comment: _"Obviously ^ is used to mark which character begins a line"_ not exactly: It represents a mark *before* the first character of a line, but it doesn't mark any character at all, it marks just the position before that character.  As you have been answered in other place, the `^` char inside square brackets means a completely different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block like this `[]` means whatever symbol that is between those brackets.

For example, `[abc]` matches either `a`, `b`, or `c`.

But, if the first char of this block is a `^`, it means whatever symbol that is *not* between those to brackets:

for example, `[^abc]` matches `d`, `e`, `?`, `\n` (a new line),  (a space), etc.

So, `[^]` means anything that is not in the empty set, or what is the same thing, the whole set of chars (and this includes the `\n` char)

The "regular" dot (`.`) matches anything, *except* a new line (`\n`). So, this is the equivalent of `[^\n]`. I said "regular" because you can specify an option to make the dot match *anything*. So, it'd be the equivalent of `[^]`.